# "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error on Contribution page

Tags: civicontribute

I'm relatively new to CiviCRM and am excited to learn more about the application in the future.  I have a Wordpress site created using Elementor.  I have plenty of contacts and donations in the CiviCRM database.  I'd like to implement a proper CiviContribute contribution page.  I set up a payment processor and the contribution page, but no matter what I do, I get this "404 - Not Found" error.  Other than that, everything works fine.

I've tried disabling all the other plugins, and don't see anything in the log file in the ConfigAndLog directory.  I'm at a loss - any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Here's the link to the contribution page:  https://maranathacm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=3

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM! This was a good formulated question. It is good practice to state both CiviCRM and CMS version, when asking these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the base page is set - go to https://maranathacm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1

Review the Base Page setting and value, it cannot be blank

Make sure there is a published page that matches the one in that page

If there is no value there, add one, civicrm is the default and then create a WP page with that slug

Make sure the page is public and visible to all

Once you've done that (or confirmed the base page exists) Visit this page https://maranathacm.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Confirm that your permalinks are set to anything EXCEPT Plain

If it is set to Plain change to one of the other options and save

If it is not set to plain, you can exit the page

Flush CiviCRM Caches go to https://maranathacm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1 and click cleanup caches